# pinch to zoom with pan gesture in maui blazor application

Tags: asp.net, razor, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

i have a image and when ever i pinch to zoom it, i should be able to move the image with fingers(pan gesture) with the same level of zoomed.

i tried some mouseoverevents and im able to do separately pinch to zoom and pan gesture,but together am facing some issues in maui blazor application.please resolve it.
i have tried the following code

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class ZoomPanContentView : ContentView
    {
        private double startScale = 1;
        private double currentScale = 1;
        private double xOffset = 0;
        private double yOffset = 0;

        public ZoomPanContentView()
        {
            var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
            pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
            GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);

            var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
            panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
            GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
        }

        private void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started)
            {
                startScale = Content.Scale;
                Content.AnchorX = 0;
                Content.AnchorY = 0;
            }
            else if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)
            {
                currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
                currentScale = Math.Max(1, currentScale);
                currentScale = Math.Min(currentScale, 5);

                var renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
                var deltaX = renderedX / Width;
                var deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
                var originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

                var renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
                var deltaY = renderedY / Height;
                var deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
                var originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

                var targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
                var targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

                var transX = targetX.Clamp(-Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
                var transY = targetY.Clamp(-Content.Height * (currentScale - 1), 0);

                Content.Scale = currentScale;
                Content.TranslateTo(transX, transY, 0);
            }
        }

        private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentScale == 1)
                return;

            switch (e.StatusType)
            {
                case GestureStatus.Running:
                    var xTrans = xOffset + e.TotalX;
                    var yTrans = yOffset + e.TotalY;
                    Content.TranslateTo(xTrans, yTrans, 0);
                    break;
                case GestureStatus.Completed:
                    xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
                    yOffset = Content.TranslationY;

                    var maxTransX = Math.Min(0, Content.Width * (currentScale - 1));
                    var maxTransY = Math.Min(0, Content.Height * (currentScale - 1));
                    xOffset = Math.Max(maxTransX, xOffset);
                    yOffset = Math.Max(maxTransY, yOffset);

                    var minTransX = Math.Max(Width - Content.Width * currentScale, 0);
                    var minTransY = Math.Max(Height - Content.Height * currentScale, 0);
                    xOffset = Math.Min(minTransX, xOffset);
                    yOffset = Math.Min(minTransY, yOffset);

                    Content.TranslateTo(xOffset, yOffset, 500, Easing.BounceOut);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) *"facing some issues"* - what does that mean? 2) Why do you have `using xamarin.forms;` in a maui app? Remove that line; does code still compile? 3) A `ContentView` isn't inside a `Blazor component`, so I don't think `(asp.net, razor, blazor, or maui-blazor)` are relevant tags. Are you trying to pinch-zoom a `BlazorWebView`, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue what you are facing can be resolved using the JS Hammer library.
Below is the snippet for pinch-to-zoom with pan gestures on an image.

Add the CDN

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs"></script>
```

Add the JavaScript file:

```
function hammerIt(elm) {
    var hammertime = new Hammer(elm, {});
    hammertime.get('pinch').set({ enable: true });

    var posX = 0,
        posY = 0,
        scale = 1,
        last_scale = 1,
        last_posX = 0,
        last_posY = 0,
        max_pos_x = 0,
        max_pos_y = 0,
        transform = "",
        el = elm;

    hammertime.on('doubletap pan pinch panend pinchend', function (ev) {
        if (ev.type == "doubletap") {
            transform = "translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(2, 2, 1)";
            scale = 2;
            last_scale = 2;

            if (window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('-webkit-transform').toString() != "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)") {
                transform = "translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1)";
                scale = 1;
                last_scale = 1;
            }

            el.style.webkitTransform = transform;
            transform = "";
        }
        
        // Pan
        if (scale != 1) {
            posX = last_posX + ev.deltaX;
            posY = last_posY + ev.deltaY;
            max_pos_x = Math.ceil((scale - 1) * el.clientWidth / 2);
            max_pos_y = Math.ceil((scale - 1) * el.clientHeight / 2);

            if (posX > max_pos_x) {
                posX = max_pos_x;
            }
            if (posX < -max_pos_x) {
                posX = -max_pos_x;
            }
            if (posY > max_pos_y) {
                posY = max_pos_y;
            }
            if (posY < -max_pos_y) {
                posY = -max_pos_y;
            }
        }
        if (ev.type == "pinch") {
            scale = Math.max(.999, Math.min(last_scale * ev.scale, 4));
        }
        if (ev.type == "pinchend") {
            last_scale = scale;
        }

        // Panend
        if (ev.type == "panend") {
            last_posX = posX < max_pos_x ? posX : max_pos_x;
            last_posY = posY < max_pos_y ? posY : max_pos_y;
        }

        if (scale != 1) {
            transform = "translate3d(" + posX + "px, " + posY + "px, 0) scale3d(" + scale + ", " + scale + ", 1)";
        }

        if (transform) {
            el.style.webkitTransform = transform;
        }
    });
}
```

And invoke it from your Razor page:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS;
@page "/zoom-pan-pinch"
<h3>Zoom</h3>

<img id="myImage" @ref="imageRef" src="./Nature.jpg" alt="Image" />
 
 @code {
     private ElementReference imageRef;
 
     protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
     {
         if (firstRender)
         {
             await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("hammerIt", imageRef);
         }
     }
 }
```

I have tested it and it worked fine for me. Please test and revert.